# Material UI Input field autocomplete=off not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I am using Input field from material-ui along with react, trying to set autofill off for all the fields and have tried multiple solutions available but none of them seems working properly. Tried Solutions -

- By setting **autoComplete="off"**
- Passed autocomplete:'off' in the **InputProps**
- By setting random name for the field - this is working but doesn't allow to enter anything into input field
- By setting unique ID/ClassName/Name attribute
- via JS script

But none of them seems working fine.
Can anyone help me with the working solution?

Comment: Please share a code you've tried !! So, we can look into it.

Comment: There is nothing fancy in code actually, simeple input field of material UI with all the code mentioned above in question

Comment: So you mean autocomplete off in simple input field is not working in formik and works well in other components?

Comment: Which Material UI version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Pass `autoComplete="off"` to the `InputProps`, not directly to Autocomplete

```
<Autocomplete
  ...
  InputProps={{
    autocomplete: "off"
  }}
/>
```

Comment: thanks but have tried this as well, question updated.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below approaches for this issue.

Set the autoComplete attribute to off. This is the simplest way to disable autofill, and it should work in most browsers.

```
<TextField
  autoComplete="off"
  label="Username"
  name="username"
  />
```

Pass the autocomplete prop to the InputProps object. This is another way to disable autofill, and it is more flexible than setting the autoComplete attribute directly.

```
 <TextField
      InputProps={{
        autocomplete: "off",
      }}
      label="Username"
      name="username"
      />
```

Also you can try below JS code to use a JS script to disable autofill. This is the most secure way to disable autofill, but it is also the most complex.

```
const disableAutocomplete = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((input) => {
    input.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
  });
};

disableAutocomplete();
```